# Camera Roll cannot be opened in my app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Camera Roll cannot be opened in my app.
In this controller, my goal is to select photos and send them to the server.
PhotoController is like

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class PhotoController:UIViewController,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func PhotoSelect(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    @IBAction func PhotoSend(_ sender: Any) {
        let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        myPickerController.delegate = self;
        myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

        self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

      private func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])

    {
        myImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //myImageUploadRequest()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

  }
```

Traceback is

> 2017-06-12 14:04:43.054105 Kenshin_Swift[265:8781] Unknown class
>   PhotoController in Interface Builder file.
>       2017-06-12 14:04:46.320479 Kenshin_Swift[265:8781] -[UIViewController PhotoSelect:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100a0c9d0
>       2017-06-12 14:04:46.323252 Kenshin_Swift[265:8781] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[UIViewController PhotoSelect:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x100a0c9d0'
>       *** First throw call stack:
>       (0x184a211b8 0x18345855c 0x184a28268 0x184a25270 0x18491e80c 0x18a90bd30 0x18a90bcb0 0x18a8f6128 0x18a90b59c 0x18a90b0c4
>   0x18a906328 0x18a8d6da0 0x18b0c075c 0x18b0ba130 0x1849ceb5c
>   0x1849ce4a4 0x1849cc0a4 0x1848fa2b8 0x1863ae198 0x18a9417fc
>   0x18a93c534 0x1000f5274 0x1838dd5b8)
>       libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

When I run my app on my real iPhone, my app stopped and this error happen.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRZ6M.png)

I do not know why this error happen.Not codes but other setting is wrong, right?How can I fix this?

My info.plist  is 
[info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFFWY.png)

Comment: There is some problem with your class. Delete your current class and try doing the same code making a new class.

Comment: Unknown class PhotoController in Interface Builder file. -> Check Interface Builder and add PhotoController name in Viewcontroller

Comment: Check if the outlet connections from the button to the action are correct. Just to be sure right click on the button and remove the connection and link it again.

Comment: you create an action method called PhotoSelect. Check out into your interface builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have not provide privacy security in your info.plist.

Privacy - Camera Usage Description -> for camera.

Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description  -> for photo library.

```
if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary) {
       let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
       imagePicker.delegate = self
       imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
       self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

try this above code, if it does not work then check your IBAction PhotoSend Method outlet in Connection Inspector.

Comment: thx, I add these code to my info.plist.I updated my question and I added my info.plist info .But same error happen.What should I do?

Comment: thx, I add ur code, but "Expected declaration" error happen.I wrote ur code in the place between my  @IBAction func PhotoSend &  private func imagePickerController.Do u think the place of my code is wrong?(If it is true,please tell me which part is right)

Comment: Have you check your @IBAction func PhotoSend() outlet connection in Connection Inspector ?

Comment: You have to put above code in @IBAction func PhotoSend().

Answer (score 0):

From the error traceback I believe the problem is with your IBAction Outlet `@IBAction func PhotoSelect(_ sender: Any)`.
Please check the outlet for

```
 @IBAction func PhotoSelect(_ sender: Any) {
    }
```

in the interface builder and see whether you have added the outlet properly.